# Make a single array from an array containing arrays?

Tags: ruby

Is there any Ruby library to make:

```
a = [[1,2,3], [4], [5,6]]
```

into:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

using something like `a.to_single_array`?

Comment: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-flatten `Array#flatten`

Comment: What is "the documentation"? What is "flatten"? http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-flatten

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about not bothering even to consult the basic documentation.

Comment: To be fair, you sort of need to know the vocabulary "flatten" to be able to search this.

Comment: To be fair, it only take a few minutes to read through the Array documentation to find `flatten`. It's a necessary part of programming to do so.

Comment: I'm sorry that I didn't read `Array` documentation. Could you please guys help me to close this question. It's so embarrassing and it's hurts when you guys placing such kind of comments. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`flatten`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-flatten) will do the magic.

```
1.9.3-p429 :017 > a = [[1,2,3], [4], [5,6]]
 => [[1, 2, 3], [4], [5, 6]]
1.9.3-p429 :018 > a.flatten
 => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
1.9.3-p429 :019 >
```

Answer (score 3):

`a.flatten!` will perform the action on "a" itself.

```
1.9.3p448 :017 > a
 => [1, 2, [1, 2]]
1.9.3p448 :018 > a.flatten!
 => [1, 2, 1, 2]
1.9.3p448 :019 > a
 => [1, 2, 1, 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's exactly what [Array#flatten](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-flatten) does.

```
irb(main):001:0> [[1,2,3], [4], [5,6]].flatten
=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```